# Junit test always returns false

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a service having a method that checks if a product exists. Returns true if found else false. But when i create a unit test class and call the method it always returns false even if the product exists. When i run the application and test using postman, it worked as expected,returning true when found else false.

The service class(Works as expected when i consume api using postman through a controller)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {this.productRepository = productRepository;}

    //check if a product exists
    public boolean checkIfProductExists(String name)
    {
        Product product =  productRepository.findByName(name);
        if(product != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The test

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductServiceTests {

    @MockBean
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfProductExistsTest()
    {  
       //result is supposed to be true because ARVs exists
       //when i consume api using postman it returns true, but here false
       //why is it always false no matter the input
       boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("ARVs");

       //therefore test fails but it is supposed to pass
       assertEquals(true,result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unit testing `ProductService` and you're mocking the same. This is not how unit testing works.

You mock the dependencies of `ProductService` which is `ProductRepository` in this case.

So, your test should look like

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private ProductRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        Mockito.when(repository.findProductByName(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(new Product());

        boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("some product name");

        assertEquals(true, result);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public ProductService productService(final ProductRepository repository) {

        return new ProductService(repository);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mock the response for `productRepository`

```
when(productRepository.findByName("ARVs")).thenReturn(myProduct);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mocking `ProductService` will always result in `false`. What you should do is mocking `ProductRepository` and inject it in `ProductService`. Also, if you want to reproduce the situation in which "ARVs" exists, you should instruct your mock.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductServiceTests {

    @MockBean
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfProductExistsTest()
    {  
       Product myProduct = new Product();
     Mockito.when(productRepository.findByName("ARVs")).thenReturn(myProduct);
       boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("ARVs");

       assertEquals(true,result);
    }
}
```

If you do not tell the mocked object how to behave, then it will return you always a `null` for objects and a `false` for `boolean` variables.

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't understood what should be mocked

Answer (score 1):

This test kind of doesn't make sense. I believe you've meant to check `ProductService`'s code, but then you create a Mockito's mock for it, that by default will return false upon the call to `checkIfProductxists` with any parameter whatsoever.

If your intention is to check `ProductService` - it can't be a mock (use `@Autowired` instead of mock bean`).
You might want to consider mocking the repository instead to avoid the DB calls.

So you should `@MockBean ProductRepository productRepository;` and then register expectations on it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // you might need to supply some kind of context configuration here as well so that spring will know what beans should be really loaded
public class ProductServiceTest {


 @Autowired ProductService productService;

 @MockBean ProductRepository productRepo;

 @Test
 public void checkIfProductExistsTest() {


  when(productRepo.findByName("ARVs")).thenReturn(<some_product_instance>);

  boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("ARVs");
  assertTrue(result);
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks I've understood

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be looking for something like this for the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductServiceTests {

    @Autoired
    private ProductService productService;

    @MockBean ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    public void checkTrueIfProductExists()
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        Mockito.when(productRepository.findByName(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(product)
        boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("foo");

        assertTrue(result);
    }



    @Test
    public void checkFalseIfProductDoesntExists()
    {
        Mockito.when(productRepository.findByName(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null)
        boolean result = productService.checkIfProductExists("bar");

        assertFalse(result);
    }
}
```

What you had before declared your ProductService as a mock where in fact we did want to wire this in and then mock the repository. This then allows us to control the results the repository brings back using something like Mockito.